# how to solve proftpd very slow connection?

Tags: mysql, ftp, proftpd

I'm having big trouble with my proftpd installation: the login is slow as hell, it takes about 10 seconds and more and that's to much for the default settings of most ftp clients. i'm using mysql and mod_sql as backend for the login.

I've already searched a bit and added the following to my proftpd configuration:

```
UseReverseDNS off
IdentLookups off
ServerIdent on “...”
```

But that did not help at all. Mysql is already set to not make any DNS lookups.

At the moment I have no idea, what to try next -- do you have any?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Maybe there is some invalid DNS entries in your interfaces config files?

Comment: thanks for your suggestion -- no ... the DNS entries are correct. i also thought, that proftpd should avoid any DNS lookups when specifying the above configuration options?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

here's the answer for my problem:

apparently the SQLAuthenticate directive was the problem. it was set to:

```
SQLAuthenticate users userset
```

i've changed this to

```
SQLAuthenticate users
```

now authentication is fast as hell.

i've found a howto on the proftpd site, that explains why this configuration may cause problems:

http://www.proftpd.org/docs/howto/SQL.html